# Spell Check Issue In Microsoft Word Installed In Ubuntu Via Wine

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I am using microsoft word 2007 in ubuntu. The office is installed through wine.The problem is that spell check is not working in the word documents.Most of the proofing options are disabled and greyed.

How to enable the spell check?

Comment: Are you sure they are disabled, can you provide a screenshot of what you see, did you install do a custom or default installation?

Comment: Yes I did the custom installation. I had installed word,PPT and XL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repair or reinstall office to fix it. It worked for me.